# How can I solve this error on my code using discord.js?: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

...

client.on('ready', function(){
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity(">help | check Commands"); 
});

client.on('message', function(msg){
    if(msg.content[0] === '>'){ //'msg.content' is command in this instance
        if(msg.content.slice(1)==='ladder'){
            let voice = new Discord.VoiceChannel()
            if(!voice){
                console.log("Error : need any Channel")
            }
            else{
                //msg.reply(voice.members())
                console.log(voice.members())
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is code of bot.js using discord.js.

I intend to read members in discord voice channel.
When I call Bot-Commands named "ladder", bot reads members in my voicechannel.

But an error occurs below. I can't check members.

```
/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildChannel.js:28
super(guild.client, data);
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
at new GuildChannel (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildChannel.js:28:17)
at new VoiceChannel (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/VoiceChannel.js:13:1)
at Client.<anonymous> (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/bot.js:59:25)
at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:825:20)
at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Receiver.dataMessage (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:437:14)
at Receiver.getData (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:367:17)
at Receiver.startLoop (/home/bitnami/project/Casper_registration_form/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:143:22)
```

I read api-docs about VoiceChannel.members on discord.js but I don't understand yet.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you post what's on/around line 59 of your `bot.js` file?

Comment: Oh Sorry, I didn't write line num. line 59 is "let voice = new Discord.VoiceChannel()"

Comment: You didn't pass the `guild` and `data.type` to the constructor, but... What do you want to achieve by using `new Discord.VoiceChannel()`?

Comment: I want to get member list on my voice channel. And make simple feature like lottery.I read that VoiceChannel() have '.members' property..But I can't understand about guild and how to use.

Comment: Thanks! I'll study more about discord.js

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try, I think this will be useful

```
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client()

var prefix = '>'

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    client.user.setActivity({ type: 'LISTENING', name: '>help | check Commands' })
})

client.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) {

        const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if (command === 'ladder') {
            if (!msg.member.voice.channel) return msg.channel.send('First you need to join a voice channel');

            let members = msg.member.voice.channel.members

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Member list of ${msg.member.voice.channel.name} channel`)
                .setDescription(members.map((i) => `${members.array().indexOf(i) + 1}. ${i}`).join("\n"))

            msg.channel.send(embed)
        }
    }
})

client.login('Token')
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I'll try it!